# Line break in Page / Node Titles

Tags: theming

Is there some way we can use `<br>` or javascript line breaks in Node, Page and/or Block Title fields?

Comment: do you want the page break in content or title?

Comment: i need line breaks in titles

Comment: where have I mentioned body

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing HTML in block title - where is $block->subject created?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56786/allowing-html-in-block-title-where-is-block-subject-created)

Comment: Similar to this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10257/drupal-7-how-to-break-title-of-content-into-multiple-lines ?

Comment: this seems to be the solution for block titles, but still looking for a simple solution to insert <br> tags in node titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need that - or something similar - I mostly type something like 'title|subtitle' right in the title field.
Then right before rendering, I replace all '|' chars with breaks.

And recently, someone wanted bold & line breaks in titles, so I added a textarea with WYSIWYG and auto-filled the real title field ( that I put hidden ) with a stripped down version of what was in the textarea.

So basically, I use work-arounds. Just a thought.

To solve your problem for Blocks, you can always use the Bean module. That way, you can make different 'types' of Blocks, all fieldable. And then implement the method I used with the WYSIWYG.

Comment: Thanks, I have used duble pipe sign || and replaced that through javascript. Pipe signs automaticaly removed from page title.

Answer (score 1):

I have found there is good reason why Drupal restricts html in titles. If you need a subtitle, it is best to create an additional field in the content type, then position it using the Display Suite module.

Comment: I agree that there must be some good reasons but still I want to know if there is a way. Does this aproach works for block titles ??

Comment: No, I don't think Display Suite would help with blocks. But you could still create a custom view for a block and customize an additional field below the title as well.

Answer (score -3):

Try css, change title width for pages you want to have breaks.